# Best way to extend django authentication/authorization

Tags: django, authentication

I'm adding in a Terms of Service acceptance requirement to our site and am trying to figure out the best way to handle this within [Django's authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) framework.

For simplicity's sake, here's a `UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    accepted_tos_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, editable=False, null=True)
```

So basically what I want to do is to check that `accepted_tos_at` is not `None` (or in reality greater than the date of the last TOS revision). If it passes this test then we authenticate normally, but if it is `None` all views except `login` and `tos_display` are inaccessible.

What I'm hung up on is how should you go about doing this globally? I would rather not add in `user_passes_test` decorators to every one of my views and likewise I'd like to avoid testing for this permission in every one of my views. There must be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, when you're talking about something that should apply to every view, then, you're talking about middleware. In your case, this is relatively straight-forward:

```
class AcceptTOSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(request):
        login_url = reverse('login')
        tos_url = reverse('tos_display')
        if request.path not in [login_url, tos_url]:
            profile = request.user.get_profile()
            if profile.accepted_tos_at is None or \
               profile.accepted_tos_at < settings.LAST_TOS_REVISION:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(tos_url)
        return None
```

First, this checks if the requested URL is not the login or TOS views. This prevents infinite loops if a redirect is necessary. Then, you check the `accepted_tos_at`. I assumed you're simply going to store the last revision date as a setting, so you'll need to modify that if you have other plans. If the TOS needs to be accepted, the user is redirected to the TOS view, otherwise, the middleware returns `None` which tells Django to keep processing the request as normal.

Just add the middleware to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and you're golden.

Answer (score 2):

I've done authentication recently with class-based views and mixins. Take a look at `LoginRequiredMixin` in [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views.py) for an example.

This does mean that all your views (that you want to protect) need to include a common mixin, but that's the cleanest way I know of doing it.

Usage (from the [docs](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#loginrequiredmixin)) is like this:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class SomeSecretView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "path/to/template.html"

    def get(self, request):
        return self.render_to_response({})
```

You'd probably want to define your own mixin, which might look like this (not tested):

```
class AcceptedTOSRequiredMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = request.user.get_profile()

        if not profile or profile.accepted_tos_at is None:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()  # return a forbidden response.

        return super(AcceptedTOSRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request,
                     *args, **kwargs)
```

The other ways of doing it involve decorating them at the URL level, but that's uglier in my view (I'd be happy to dig up an example of what it looks like if that'd help).