# Block url for users not in staff. Django

Tags: django, url, django-admin

I would like to block some urls for users they don't have staff status.

Now I do it checking in my code in each def

```
if not request.user.is_staff:
    ...
```

But I have so many methods and all of them are under a /app/ path, so I thought perhaps exists a way to block for non staff users the access to those methods.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a decorator for that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12271444/20972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `staff_member_required` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
```

EDIT: Code is [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py) if you need it.